# ¿Es posible responder pregunta con un enlace a YouTube donde se explica cómo resolver el problema?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, calidad-de-publicaciones

¿Es posible responder a una pregunta de un compañero que tiene x duda con un enlace a un vídeo en YouTube donde se explica el paso a paso para resolver su problema? ¿O es una mala practica dar este tipo de respuestas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Es una mala práctica responder solo con un enlace, bien sea a otra página, bien sea a Youtube.

La explicación es sencilla: el objetivo de StackOverflow en español es ser una fuente de conocimiento sobre programación en español, basándonos en preguntas y respuestas. Las respuestas no sólo deben ser útiles para el autor de la pregunta, sino para que cualquiera que en el futuro tenga el mismo problema, pueda encontrar una solución al mismo.

El problema que hay con los enlaces es que, si en el futuro el destino de los mismos desaparece (por ejemplo, un blog que es eliminado, o un video de youtube que es borrado), la respuesta queda sin contenido y deja de tener sentido para el que la consulte.

Por todo esto, lo normal es que si para responder te apoyas en un enlace externo, copies en la respuesta las partes relevantes de la misma para que siempre estén disponible en el sistema. Sin embargo si puedes después de esta respuesta añadir un enlace a Youtube o a otro blog como información complementaria a la respuesta.

Comment: Ademas agregaria que el enlace puede contener un monton de ruido que no hacen a la respuesta, una presentacion, saludos y otras cosas...

Comment: Dicho de otra manera: si es sólo un enlace ( vídeo, audio o texto ) va mejor como comentario. Ya que puede servir de referencia para que el que pregunta u otro usuario genere una respuesta en base al contenido del enlace ( mencionando fuentes y esas cosas ) y si en el futuro el enlace no está disponible, queda la interpretación / solución / respuesta.

Comment: @gbianchi Hola, [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287579/obtener-usuario-de-windows-donde-se-est%c3%a1-ejecutando-windows-form/287582#287582) pasó lo mismo que comentan en esta pregunta y el flag fue rechazado; la respuesta dice que contacte al moderador sólo para cosas que requieren de su intervención (?)

Comment: Si. Porque no es que los moderadores vamos a borrar un post porque es solo un enlace. La respuesta debe ser reportada como de baja calidad y toda la comunidad decidira si la misma debe ser eliminada o no. Usar el reporte otros para avisar esto, no es lo que corresponde. @Alfabravo

Comment: Esa opción no existe. Sólo puedo elegir "no es una respuesta"